# how set curl to module controller

Tags: php, magento2

I have a controller that sends curl to another controller, but I get an error 302.

this is my curl in magento2

```
         try{
            $_str_base_url = $urlInterface->getUrl('magento_ebayautopurchase/EbayApiScanningData/EbayData');

            //if the method is get
            $this->_curl->get($_str_base_url);
            //response will contain the output in form of JSON string
            $response = $this->_curl->getBody();

          var_dump('tested');
          var_dump($response);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            var_dump('catch');
        }
```

[image]

Comment: 302 means redirect. Probably this is a part of your site that needs authentication.

Comment: you don't know how, how use authentication in magento2?